# How to vote in SharePoint Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, voting

Sometimes I want to vote on important questions, but I do not get any link or option to do it.

Is there any rule for voting?

Answer (score 4):

The features you have available to you depend on **how much the system trusts you**. This is determined by reputation.

Concerning voting specifically, you cannot vote up until reaching 15 reputation, and cannot vote down until reaching 100 reputation. There is a complete list of privileges and reputation votes required for each of them [on our FAQ page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Errr... the big up arrow just above the number of votes on the left hand side of your question.